# How to convert getBalance output to ether in web3 1.0

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I tried web3.js 1.0.0-beta.

I found in document method web3.utils.fromWei(value, 'ether') convert the wei to ether. In new version getBalance method work as asynchronous. how can I get the value from getBlance then passed as Big number

I tried

`web3.utils.fromWei( 
 web3.eth.getBalance("0x90f8bf6a479f320ead074411a4b0e7944ea8c9c1"),'ether');`

But got error!

Comment: This isn't really an Ethereum question. You use web3.js's asynchronous functions the same way you use _any_ asynchronous functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a simple Web3.js sample which fetches the balance of an Ethereum address:
https://github.com/shawntabrizi/ETH-Balance

This is using Web3.js 0.2x.x, but the only difference here for Web3.js 1.0 is to change `web3.fromWei` to `web3.utils.fromWei`.

Thus by simply making that one small change, you can get the call to start working:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address, function (error, wei) {
    if (!error) {
        var balance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether');
        console.log(balance + " ETH");
    }
});
```

You can also read [my blog post which discusses how to make Web3.js work asynchronously with JavaScript Promises](http://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/making-web3-js-work-asynchronously-javascript-promises-await/).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use promise instead of call back:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address).then(result => web3.utils.fromWei(result,"ether"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used async, then you need to add await as well:

```
 const getBalance = async () => {
    const balance = web3.utils.fromWei(
      await web3.eth.getBalance(address),
      "ether"
    );
```